# Extracting avg time spent at a place from Google

Tags: java, android, google-maps, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to extract the average time spent at a place straight from Google's search results; as Google API does not support fetching of that info at the moment.

For example,

url is "https://www.google.com/search?q=vivocity" and the text to extract is "15 min to 2 hr"

I've tried the following code

```
try {
        String url = "https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=vivocity";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("mozilla/17.0").get();
        Elements ele = doc.select("div._B1k");

        for (Element qwer:ele){
            temp += "Avg time spent: " + qwer.getElementsByTag("b").first().text() + "\n";
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried just outputing doc.text() and searching through the output, it doesn't seem to contain anything to do with avg time taken too.

Strange thing is with other URLs and divs, they work perfectly fine.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If the source code of the page doesn't contain required text, I guess that this data might be loaded into page later via some AJAX call.

Comment: Hi xomena, thanks for the reply. Is there any other library I can use to retrieve the text after the AJAX call?